# SYSCALL_DEFINE6(...)

Tags: c, memory, linux-kernel

I am now studying about the implementation of page table of Linux 2.6.38.8. In `linux/include/linux/syscall.c`, I found that

```
#define SYSCALL_DEFINE6(name, ...) SYSCALL_DEFINEx(6, _##name, __VA_ARGS__)
```

but I don't fully understand what this piece of code is doing. There are some branches for

```
SYSCALL_DEFINEx(6, _##name, __VA_ARGS__)
```

and their definition, but the code is quite complicated to understand for me. If anyone know about this implementation, teach me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically SYSCALL_DEFINE is defined by another define which is called SYSCALL_DEFINEx. In addition it used string concatenation to build the second parameter, which is the same name preceded by the "_" character. In addition it uses **VA_ARGS** (this is a c99 feature) which passes all the specified parameters to the SYSCALL_DEFINEx macro.

Comment: is the macro defining a new system call? for example, I ended up to see "SYSCALL_DEFINITION6(mmap_pgoff, ...)". Then it's translated to "asmlinkage long sys_mmap_pgoff()" function.


here is a bit another question. where is implementation of "asmlinkage long sys_mmap_pgoff()" function? and where and when is this function invoked?

Thanks,

Comment: Yes it is the definition of a system call, in your case the mmap system call.